# does closing of web browser window cause the termination of php script?

Tags: php

I have a special php script that I call from a browser. It does lots of things and it runs for about 15mins. It does stream back some results.

My question is what happens if I close the browser windows? Is the php script terminated? If yes, can I make it somehow not to be affected when the browser window is closed?

Comment: For the love of god, please use a cron job for things like this!

Comment: to run create new db2 database if I need it? or create a backup if need it?

Comment: Well then, at least use a CLI script, or fork a new process, or use a daemon/worker/queue pattern for long running jobs. A plain script run through the web server is not usually the place to do time consuming operations.

Comment: well, I didn't program it I `only` use the script. I can suggest what you say though :-) But I have no idea what you're talking about :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ignore_user_abort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php) to tell PHP to keep running even when the connection is broken.

Comment: so the answer is yes unless I use `ignore_user_abort`? what about the `When running PHP as a command line script`. Does it apply only if the php script runs only from command line?

Comment: @Radek Yes, the script will terminate _unless_ you call `ignore_user_abort(true)`. The same applies when you run it from the command line, though there are better ways to keep a process running in the background in the command line. (cron, screen, etc.)

Comment: cool, so it's clear now. So basically if there is a script tell you that  you cannot close the window otherwise it won't finish correctly it means that it is poorly coded script?

Comment: @Radek As a rule of thumb, scripts called from the browser shouldn't do anything that takes more than a few seconds. Anything longer should be run from the command line or cron.

Comment: keep in mind that the php script does not necessarily stop when the browser is "gone", even though it generally does. It has to do with how soon the web server realizes the connection is gone, and php must realize that from the web server too.